# Which stylesheet will be selected for browser's print command?

Tags: css

Which stylesheet will be used when the page is printed from the browser’s print command with the below code?

```
<link rel="stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=”core.css”>
<link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” media=”screen” href=”comman.css”>
```

1. core.css
2. common.css
3. core.css + common.css
4. Varies from browser to browser

Again this question is from a quiz.

Comment: 4th option makes me to post this here. I don't have all browser/environment with me. Though I will check with mine & post it

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be

***Varies from browser to browser***

If you need to include a media type for a printable document then you have to use the ***print*** media type which is intended for paged material and for documents viewed on screen in print preview mode.

Media type ***screen*** is intended primarily for color computer screens.

Since this media type is not specified in any of the style sheet I think the browser setting will decide how to print the data.

For detailed information see

[Media Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)